# Reading multiple values from a text file in powershell then manipulating the values

Tags: powershell

Forgive the novice question, i'm new to powershell and am trying to do something which should be very easy!

i have a text file with the following contents

```
DEVICE ID:   {E24CF707-F030-48DC-8E1A-59B96148BF52}
DEVICE NAME: All Devices (RAINBOW-SRV)
TYPE:        Drive pool
DEVICE ID:   {D16DC75F-8A8B-4AEC-A411-9B0BC58CBF16}
DEVICE NAME: HP 1
TYPE:        Drive
DEVICE ID:   {F2D2AB4A-1FBE-4158-AB62-6A94AE4392E2}
DEVICE NAME: RAINBOW-SRV
TYPE:        Machine
DEVICE ID:   {23AD5D42-00A8-496B-96E5-1F5CAA3F9E9D}
DEVICE NAME: Symantec Protection Network (RAINBOW-SRV)
TYPE:        Symantec Protection Network
RETURN VALUE: 1
```

I'm trying to get  the string that follows DEVICE NAME: on each occurence into an array to pass to a command further down the line.  I've tried the following code but get an error stating that Substring is not a valid method.

I feel i'm missing something very obvious but cannot see it! any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: I think you forgot to paste your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file content, filter the lines that begins with 'DEVICE NAME: ', for each line remove (replace with nothing) 'DEVICE NAME: '

```
Get-Content devices.txt | Where-Object {$_ -like 'DEVICE NAME:* '} | Foreach-Object {$_ -repla
ce '^DEVICE NAME: '}

All Devices (RAINBOW-SRV)
HP 1
RAINBOW-SRV
Symantec Protection Network (RAINBOW-SRV)
```

UPDATE: per OT request, how to pass the value to an executable command

```
Get-Content devices.txt | 
Where-Object {$_ -like 'DEVICE NAME:* '} | 
Foreach-Object {
    $device = $_ -replace '^DEVICE NAME: '
    app.exe "$device"
}
```

Comment: $a = Get-Content C:\NetESP\BackupTapeCheck\DriveDetails.txt | Select-String "DEVICE NAME: "
foreach ($line in $a) {$line.Substring(13)}

Comment: It doesn't work because $line is a MatchInfo object and it doesn't have a Substring method. You have to refer to its Line property: $line.line.Substring(13). You could also convert it to string in many other ways, such as: "$line".Substring(13), or $line.ToString().Substring(13)

Comment: Thanks Shay, i've been trying for longer than i care to admit to get that back to a string!

Comment: Whilst i've got this open, do you know how i'd then pass each of these lines to an executable command one at a time?  I assume the 4 values are in an array but not sure what the name of it would be?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
$list = @((get-content devices.txt) | where { $_ -match "DEVICE NAME:\s*(?<Device>.+)\s*" } | %{ $matches["Device"] })

$list
```

Comment: I frequently use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
Get-Content -Path .\devices.txt |
    Select-String 'DEVICE NAME: ' |
        Foreach-Object {
            $_.ToString() -replace '^DEVICE NAME: ','app.exe '
        }
```